# MBP 2015 with Iris Pro Only and External Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, gpu

I'm about to buy a MBP edition 2015 (15'').

There are two models:

- model having only Intel Iris Pro  (without dedicated graphic card)
- model having Radeon graphic card

I don't play video games, and I do not use 3D/video softwares.
Mostly programming softwares.

However, I want to use an Apple Thunderbolt screen of 27'' as external and additional monitor.

Should the model having only Iris Pro be enough to handle this monitor (multiple-displays)?

Comment: what size is the screen? (13 or 15 inch)

Comment: 15. I updated the post.

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with Apple's Iris but I have been able to connect and run one of my PC's to an HD television without a dedicated graphics card.

Comment: I have asked what they are running at the Apple Stores, and it seems to be a macbook pro (base model) with a 27" thunderbolt display.

Comment: They have macbook pro linked to external monitor in apple stores?

Comment: @Mik378 In Canada they do when they are doing training sessions. A few years ago they did in the Upper Canada Mall store. They sometimes use the Macbook Air though.

Comment: I think they were only running Intel Graphics 4000 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphics and Video support

Intel Iris Pro Graphics​
2.2GHz - 256GB

Intel Iris Pro Graphics
2.5GHz - 512GB

Intel Iris Pro Graphics

```
AMD Radeon R9 M370X with 2GB GDDR5 memory and automatic graphics switching
Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native 
resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on up to two
external displays, both at millions of colors
```

Thunderbolt digital video output

```
Native Mini DisplayPort output
DVI, VGA, dual-link DVI and HDMI output supported using Mini DisplayPort adapters (sold separately)
Support for up to 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz on a single external display (model with AMD Radeon R9 M370X only)
```

HDMI video output 
    Support for 1080p resolution at up to 60Hz
    Support for 3840-by-2160 resolution at 30Hz
    Support for 4096-by-2160 resolution at 24Hz

retrieved from https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719?locale=en_US

Comment: Nice! So I can be confident since I don't plan to use a 5120x2880 monitor but one or two 3840x2160.

Comment: "Support for up to 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz on a single external display (model with AMD Radeon R9 M370X only)". This line may confirm that with lower resolutions, Intel Iris Pro is supposed to make the job.

Answer (score 0):

I had the 2011 Mac Air and it happily drove the external 27" thunderbolt display (2560x1440) - and it only had a 384MB Intel chip. The MBP is designed for multiple monitors - mine has 2 external 2560x1440 monitors plus its internal screen running at 2880x1800.